# boost spirint x3 phrase_parse confusion

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-variant

I defined the output of literal_string as std:: string：

```
namespace parsesss {
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
auto const literal_string = x3::rule<class literal_string,std::string>{"literal_string"};
auto const literal_string_def = x3::lexeme['"' >> +(x3::char_ - '"') >> '"'];

BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(literal_string);
}
```

Then I tested with the following code and the results also met expectations：

```
    std::string test = "\"asdfjalsdjflajsdlfjalsdf\" \"xxxxxxxxxxasdfjalsdjflajsdlfjalsdf\"";
    std::vector<std::string> out;
    bool r = parse::x3::phrase_parse(test.begin(), test.end(), *(parsesss::literal_string), parse::x3::ascii::space, out);
    if(r && (parse::g_iter == parse::g_end)){
        std::cout << "parse success!" << std::endl;
    }else{
        std::cerr << "parse fail!" << std::endl;
    }
```

But when I use variant data structures to store output, std:: string degenerates into char, why is this。

```
struct constant : x3::variant<long,char,double,float,int>{
    using base_type::base_type;
    using base_type::operator=;
};
struct last : x3::variant<std::string,char,constant>{
    using base_type::base_type;
    using base_type::operator=;
};


//
    std::string test = "\"asdfjalsdjflajsdlfjalsdf\" \"xxxxxxxxxxasdfjalsdjflajsdlfjalsdf\"";
    std::vector<last> out;
    bool r = parse::x3::phrase_parse(test.begin(), test.end(), *(parsesss::literal_string), parse::x3::ascii::space, out);
    if(r && (parse::g_iter == parse::g_end)){
        std::cout << "parse success!" << std::endl;
    }else{
        std::cerr << "parse fail!" << std::endl;
    }
```

Who can tell me why,

Or where can I find more detailed questions about this aspect on the official website。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variant attribute can be constructed from a `char`, which is preferred.

If you drop `char` from the variant element type list, it will work:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3844c5139c7c3307)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/support/ast/variant.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

namespace AST {
    using x3::variant;
    struct constant : variant<long, double, float, int> {
        using base_type::base_type;
        using base_type::operator=;
    };

    struct last : variant<std::string, constant> {
        using base_type::base_type;
        using base_type::operator=;
    };

    template <typename... T> static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, variant<T...> const& v) {
        return boost::apply_visitor([&os](auto&& v) -> auto& { return os << v; }, v);
    }
}

namespace parsesss {
    auto const literal_string     = x3::rule<class literal_string, std::string>{"literal_string"};
    auto const literal_string_def = x3::lexeme['"' >> *~x3::char_('"') >> '"'];

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(literal_string);
} // namespace parsesss

int main() {
    std::string const test = R"("asdf" "xxx yyy")";

    if (std::vector<AST::last> out;
        phrase_parse(test.begin(), test.end(), *(parsesss::literal_string) >> x3::eoi, x3::space, out))
        for (auto& el : out) {
            std::cout << " - " << el << std::endl;
        }
    else
        std::cout << "fail (" << quoted(test) << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
 - asdf
 - xxx yyy
```

### Attempts

I tried hinting the attribute system with traits:

```
template <> struct x3::traits::is_substitute<AST::last, std::string> : std::true_type {};
```

But, not unexpectedly, that didn't work.

### Working Workarounds

What you *can* do instead is to break the compatibility of "char":

```
struct Char {
    char value;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Char ch) { return os << '\'' << ch.value << '\''; }
};
```

This already works ([live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/baf42857a324c596)). You can do shorter here: ([live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39ada5f1e9f3f6cd) as well)

```
enum Char : char;
```

However, I noticed that these will just give you other trouble when you do want to parse the char literals...

## Solution

So instead, I took the flight forwards and made some rules to match all the AST nodes.

As a rule of thumb, being explicit about attribute congruence helps. For example, the "naive" expression for `constant` will not work:

```
constant = x3::double_ | x3::int_;
```

For two reasons:

- `double_` will eagerly consume integral numbers. We avoid that by substituting `strict_real_policies`
- `x3::int_` is ambiguously compatible with either `double` or `intmax_t`. Now, there will be an `x3` [numeric parser](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/spirit_x3/quick_reference/numeric.html) like `x3::long_long` that happens to match `intmax_t`, but it's better to be exact

```
constant 
    = x3::real_parser<double, x3::strict_real_policies<double>>{}
    | x3::int_parser<intmax_t>{}
    ;
```

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5377acd1485d58f5)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/support/ast/variant.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

namespace AST {
    using x3::variant;

    struct constant : variant<intmax_t, double> {
        using base_type::base_type;
        using base_type::operator=;
    };

    struct last : variant<std::string, char, constant> {
        using base_type::base_type;
        using base_type::operator=;
    };

    template <typename> constexpr std::string_view tname = "?";

    template <> constexpr std::string_view tname<std::string> = "string";
    template <> constexpr std::string_view tname<intmax_t>    = "integer";
    template <> constexpr std::string_view tname<double>      = "real";
    template <> constexpr std::string_view tname<char>        = "character";
    template <> constexpr std::string_view tname<constant>    = "constant";

    template <typename... T> static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, variant<T...> const& v) {
        return boost::apply_visitor(
            [&os](auto const& v) -> auto& {
                auto type = tname<std::decay_t<decltype(v)>>;
                return os << type << '(' << v << ')';
            },
            v);
    }
}

namespace parsesss {
    auto string_lit = x3::rule<class string_lit, std::string>{"string_lit"} =
        x3::lexeme['"' >> *~x3::char_('"') >> '"'];
    auto char_lit = x3::rule<class char_lit, char>{"char_lit"} =
        x3::lexeme["'" >> ('\\' >> x3::char_ | ~x3::char_("'")) >> "'"];
    auto constant = x3::rule<class constant, AST::constant>{"constant"} =
        x3::real_parser<double, x3::strict_real_policies<double>>{} //
        | x3::int_parser<intmax_t>{};

    auto last = x3::rule<class last, AST::last>{"last"} =
        string_lit | char_lit | constant;
    
} // namespace parsesss

int main() {
    for (std::string const test :
         {
             R"("asdf" "xxx yyy")",
             R"("asdf" 'c' "xxx yyy")",
             R"("asdf" '\'' "xxx yyy")",
             R"("asdf" '\'' 3.14e4 9999 -9999 -inf +nan 3. "xxx yyy")",
         }) //
    {
        std::cout << "testcase " << quoted(test) << std::endl;
        std::vector<AST::last> out;
        if (phrase_parse(test.begin(), test.end(), *parsesss::last >> x3::eoi, x3::space, out))
            for (auto& el : out)
                std::cout << " - " << el << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << " - FAIL" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Printing

```
testcase "\"asdf\" \"xxx yyy\""
 - string(asdf)
 - string(xxx yyy)
testcase "\"asdf\" 'c' \"xxx yyy\""
 - string(asdf)
 - character(c)
 - string(xxx yyy)
testcase "\"asdf\" '\\'' \"xxx yyy\""
 - string(asdf)
 - character(')
 - string(xxx yyy)
testcase "\"asdf\" '\\'' 3.14e4 9999 -9999 -inf +nan 3. \"xxx yyy\""
 - string(asdf)
 - character(')
 - constant(real(31400))
 - constant(integer(9999))
 - constant(integer(-9999))
 - constant(real(-inf))
 - constant(real(nan))
 - constant(real(3))
 - string(xxx yyy)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It has been very helpful to me。

Also, do you know the official detailed documentation? I couldn't find any explanations for these issues in [https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/index.html]

Comment: These things aren't documented - on purpose: they're implementation details. Also, X3 is still "experimental" - so things do change.

Comment: The thing I suspect causing the question behaviour is likely an optimization that is called "passthrough atribute" where, instead of synthesizing an attribute of the rule's declared type [and moving the result into the bound attribute on success] it binds reference directly to the output attribute. There must be a place that thinks the variant can be pass-through, BUT the rule assumes a container attribute (like `std::string`) and it doesn't know how to `insert` characters into a variant. Optimizations are deliberately not documented (they _should_ be transparent). You might raise an issue.

Comment: I filed https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/issues/776 because I think it is a bug, even though it exists ever since 1.59.0

Comment: Thank you for your help and tracking. I also think it is a bug. Because I display the declaration stored as std::sting

Comment: I am currently studying Spirit x3 and I have many questions that seem to be unanswered on the official website. Can you help me look at another question。https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77291351/the-problem-of-boost-spirit-ast-recursive-dependency

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255625/discussion-between-luohe-and-sehe).