# The Problem of Boost Spirit AST Recursive Dependency

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

**

It's strange that the following error occurred during compilation. Can anyone tell me why。

As there are still many errors, I don't know if it was caused by this error。Due to the deep recursion, I am unable to paste all the code

**

```
namespace  test {

struct last;
struct pre{
    std::vector<char> cs;
    double first;
    std::vector<x3::forward_ast<last>> second;
};
struct last : x3::variant<boost::recursive_wrapper<pre>,intmax_t>{
    using base_type::base_type;
    using base_type::operator=;
};

}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(test::pre,cs,first,second);
```

test code:

```
 std::string input = R"(
    123,xxxxxx|456.00,45645,ffffffff|33.22
)";


std::vector<test::last> out;
bool r = x3::phrase_parse(input.begin(), input.end(),  ((*x3::char_ >> '|' >> x3::double_) | x3::int_) % ',', x3::ascii::space, out);
if(r && (g_iter == g_end)){
    std::cout << "parse success!" << std::endl;
}else{
    std::cerr << "parse fail!" << std::endl;
}
```

**compile error log:**

```
I:\boost_1_83_0\build\debug\include\boost/spirit/home/x3/support/ast/variant.hpp(184): error C2679: 二元“=”: 没有找到接受“_Ty”类型的右操作数的运算符(或没有可接受的转换)
        with
        [
            _Ty=boost::fusion::deque<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,double>
        ]
I:\boost_1_83_0\build\debug\include\boost/variant/variant.hpp(2172): note: 可能是“boost::variant<boost::recursive_wrapper<test::pre>,intmax_t> &boost::variant<boost::recursive_wrapper<test::pre>,intmax_t>::operator =(boost::variant<boost::recursive_wrapper<test::pre>,intmax_t> &&) noexcept(false)”
I:\boost_1_83_0\build\debug\include\boost/variant/variant.hpp(2165): note: 或    “boost::variant<boost::recursive_wrapper<test::pre>,intmax_t> &boost::variant<boost::recursive_wrapper<test::pre>,intmax_t>::operator =(const boost::variant<boost::recursive_wrapper<test::pre>,intmax_t> &)”
I:\boost_1_83_0\build\debug\include\boost/spirit/home/x3/support/ast/variant.hpp(183): note: 尝试匹配参数列表“(boost::variant<boost::recursive_wrapper<test::pre>,intmax_t>, _Ty)”时
        with
        [
            _Ty=boost::fusion::deque<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,double>
        ]
I:\boost_1_83_0\build\debug\include\boost/spirit/home/x3/support/traits/move_to.hpp(115): note: 查看对正在编译的函数 模板 实例化“boost::spirit::x3::variant<boost::recursive_wrapper<test::pre>,intmax_t> &boost::spirit::x3::variant<boost::recursive_wrapper<test::pre>,intmax_t>::operator =<boost::fusion::deque<Attribute,double>,void>(T &&) noexcept(false)”的引用
        with
        [
            Attribute=std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,
            T=boost::fusion::deque<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,double>
        ]
I:\boost_1_83_0\build\debug\include\boost/spirit/home/x3/support/traits/move_to.hpp(115): note: 查看对正在编译的函数 模板 实例化“boost::spirit::x3::variant<boost::recursive_wrapper<test::pre>,intmax_t> &boost::spirit::x3::variant<boost::recursive_wrapper<test::pre>,intmax_t>::operator =<boost::fusion::deque<Attribute,double>,void>(T &&) noexcept(false)”的引用
        with
        [
            Attribute=std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,
            T=boost::fusion::deque<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,double>
        ]
I:\boost_1_83_0\build\debug\include\boost/spirit/home/x3/support/traits/move_to.hpp(152): note: 查看对正在编译的函数 模板 实例化“void boost::spirit::x3::traits::detail::move_to<Source,Dest>(Source &,Dest &,boost::spirit::x3::traits::variant_attribute,boost::mpl::false_)”的引用
        with
        [
            Source=boost::fusion::deque<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,double>,
            Dest=value_type
        ]
I:\boost_1_83_0\build\debug\include\boost/spirit/home/x3/support/traits/move_to.hpp(196): note: 查看对正在编译的函数 模板 实例化“void boost::spirit::x3::traits::detail::move_to<T1,Dest>(Source &,Dest &,boost::spirit::x3::traits::variant_attribute)”的引用
        with
        [
            T1=boost::fusion::deque<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,double>,
            Dest=value_type,
            Source=boost::fusion::deque<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,double>
        ]
I:\boost_1_83_0\build\debug\include\boost/spirit/home/x3/operator/detail/alternative.hpp(175): note: 查看对正在编译的函数 模板 实例化“void boost::spirit::x3::traits::move_to<T1&,T2>(Source,Dest &)”的引用     
        with
        [
            T1=boost::fusion::deque<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,double>,
            T2=value_type,
            Source=boost::fusion::deque<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,double> &,
            Dest=value_type
        ]
I:\boost_1_83_0\build\debug\include\boost/spirit/home/x3/operator/detail/alternative.hpp(191): note: 查看对正在编译的函数 模板 实例化“void boost::spirit::x3::detail::move_if<true>::call<boost::fusion::deque<Attribute,double>,test::last>(T1 &,T2 &)”的引用
        with
        [
            Attribute=std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,
            T1=boost::fusion::deque<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,double>,
            T2=value_type
        ]
I:\boost_1_83_0\build\debug\include\boost/spirit/home/x3/operator/detail/alternative.hpp(209): note: 查看对正在编译的函数 模板 实例化“bool boost::spirit::x3::detail::parse_alternative<Subject,Iterator,Context,RContext,Attribute>(const Parser &,Iterator &,const Iterator &,const Context &,RContext &,Attribute &)”的引用
        with
        [
            Subject=boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::kleene<boost::spirit::x3::standard::char_type>,boost::spirit::x3::extension::as_parser<char,void>::type>,boost::spirit::x3::double_type>,
            Iterator=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>,
            Context=boost::spirit::x3::context<boost::spirit::x3::skipper_tag,const boost::spirit::x3::ascii::space_type,boost::spirit::x3::unused_type>,
            RContext=const boost::spirit::x3::unused_type,
            Attribute=value_type,
            Parser=boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::kleene<boost::spirit::x3::standard::char_type>,boost::spirit::x3::extension::as_parser<char,void>::type>,boost::spirit::x3::double_type>
        ]
I:\boost_1_83_0\build\debug\include\boost/spirit/home/x3/core/detail/parse_into_container.hpp(97): note: 查看对正在编译的函数 模板 实例化“bool boost::spirit::x3::detail::alternative_helper<Left>::parse<Iterator,Context,RContext,value_type>(Iterator &,const Iterator &,const Context &,RContext &,Attribute &) const”的引用
        with
        [
            Left=boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::kleene<boost::spirit::x3::standard::char_type>,boost::spirit::x3::extension::as_parser<char,void>::type>,boost::spirit::x3::double_type>,
            Iterator=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>,
            Context=boost::spirit::x3::context<boost::spirit::x3::skipper_tag,const boost::spirit::x3::ascii::space_type,boost::spirit::x3::unused_type>,
            RContext=const boost::spirit::x3::unused_type,
            Attribute=value_type
        ]
I:\boost_1_83_0\build\debug\include\boost/spirit/home/x3/core/detail/parse_into_container.hpp(97): note: 查看对正在编译的函数 模板 实例化“bool boost::spirit::x3::detail::alternative_helper<Left>::parse<Iterator,Context,RContext,value_type>(Iterator &,const Iterator &,const Context &,RContext &,Attribute &) const”的引用
        with
        [
            Left=boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::kleene<boost::spirit::x3::standard::char_type>,boost::spirit::x3::extension::as_parser<char,void>::type>,boost::spirit::x3::double_type>,
            Iterator=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>,
            Context=boost::spirit::x3::context<boost::spirit::x3::skipper_tag,const boost::spirit::x3::ascii::space_type,boost::spirit::x3::unused_type>,
            RContext=const boost::spirit::x3::unused_type,
            Attribute=value_type
        ]
I:\boost_1_83_0\build\debug\include\boost/spirit/home/x3/core/detail/parse_into_container.hpp(129): note: 查看对正在编译的函数 模板 实例化“bool boost::spirit::x3::detail::parse_into_container_base_impl<Parser>::call_synthesize_x<Iterator,Context,RContext,Attribute>(const Parser &,Iterator &,const Iterator &,const Context &,RContext &,Attribute &,boost::mpl::false_)”的引用
        with
        [
            Parser=boost::spirit::x3::detail::alternative_helper<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::kleene<boost::spirit::x3::standard::char_type>,boost::spirit::x3::extension::as_parser<char,void>::type>,boost::spirit::x3::double_type>>,
            Iterator=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>,
            Context=boost::spirit::x3::context<boost::spirit::x3::skipper_tag,const boost::spirit::x3::ascii::space_type,boost::spirit::x3::unused_type>,
            RContext=const boost::spirit::x3::unused_type,
            Attribute=std::vector<test::last,std::allocator<test::last>>
        ]
I:\boost_1_83_0\build\debug\include\boost/spirit/home/x3/core/detail/parse_into_container.hpp(128): note: 查看对正在编译的函数 模板 实例化“bool boost::spirit::x3::detail::parse_into_container_base_impl<Parser>::call_synthesize_x<Iterator,Context,RContext,Attribute>(const Parser &,Iterator &,const Iterator &,const Context &,RContext &,Attribute &,boost::mpl::false_)”的引用
        with
        [
            Parser=boost::spirit::x3::detail::alternative_helper<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::kleene<boost::spirit::x3::standard::char_type>,boost::spirit::x3::extension::as_parser<char,void>::type>,boost::spirit::x3::double_type>>,
            Iterator=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>,
            Context=boost::spirit::x3::context<boost::spirit::x3::skipper_tag,const boost::spirit::x3::ascii::space_type,boost::spirit::x3::unused_type>,
            RContext=const boost::spirit::x3::unused_type,
            Attribute=std::vector<test::last,std::allocator<test::last>>
        ]
I:\boost_1_83_0\build\debug\include\boost/spirit/home/x3/core/detail/parse_into_container.hpp(183): note: 查看对正在编译的函数 模板 实例化“bool boost::spirit::x3::detail::parse_into_container_base_impl<Parser>::call_synthesize<Iterator,Context,RContext,Attribute>(const Parser &,Iterator &,const Iterator &,const Context &,RContext &,Attribute &)”的引用
        with
        [
            Parser=boost::spirit::x3::detail::alternative_helper<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::kleene<boost::spirit::x3::standard::char_type>,boost::spirit::x3::extension::as_parser<char,void>::type>,boost::spirit::x3::double_type>>,
            Iterator=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>,
            Context=boost::spirit::x3::context<boost::spirit::x3::skipper_tag,const boost::spirit::x3::ascii::space_type,boost::spirit::x3::unused_type>,
            RContext=const boost::spirit::x3::unused_type,
            Attribute=std::vector<test::last,std::allocator<test::last>>
        ]
I:\boost_1_83_0\build\debug\include\boost/spirit/home/x3/core/detail/parse_into_container.hpp(183): note: 查看对正在编译的函数 模板 实例化“bool boost::spirit::x3::detail::parse_into_container_base_impl<Parser>::call_synthesize<Iterator,Context,RContext,Attribute>(const Parser &,Iterator &,const Iterator &,const Context &,RContext &,Attribute &)”的引用
        with
        [
            Parser=boost::spirit::x3::detail::alternative_helper<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::kleene<boost::spirit::x3::standard::char_type>,boost::spirit::x3::extension::as_parser<char,void>::type>,boost::spirit::x3::double_type>>,
            Iterator=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>,
            Context=boost::spirit::x3::context<boost::spirit::x3::skipper_tag,const boost::spirit::x3::ascii::space_type,boost::spirit::x3::unused_type>,
            RContext=const boost::spirit::x3::unused_type,
            Attribute=std::vector<test::last,std::allocator<test::last>>
        ]
I:\boost_1_83_0\build\debug\include\boost/spirit/home/x3/core/detail/parse_into_container.hpp(193): note: 查看对正在编译的函数 模板 实例化“bool boost::spirit::x3::detail::parse_into_container_base_impl<Parser>::call_synthesize_dispatch_by_seq<Iterator,Context,RContext,Attribute>(const Parser &,Iterator &,const Iterator &,const Context &,RContext &,Attribute &,boost::mpl::false_)”的引用
        with
        [
            Parser=boost::spirit::x3::detail::alternative_helper<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::kleene<boost::spirit::x3::standard::char_type>,boost::spirit::x3::extension::as_parser<char,void>::type>,boost::spirit::x3::double_type>>,
            Iterator=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>,
            Context=boost::spirit::x3::context<boost::spirit::x3::skipper_tag,const boost::spirit::x3::ascii::space_type,boost::spirit::x3::unused_type>,
            RContext=const boost::spirit::x3::unused_type,
            Attribute=std::vector<test::last,std::allocator<test::last>>
        ]
I:\boost_1_83_0\build\debug\include\boost/spirit/home/x3/core/detail/parse_into_container.hpp(192): note: 查看对正在编译的函数 模板 实例化“bool boost::spirit::x3::detail::parse_into_container_base_impl<Parser>::call_synthesize_dispatch_by_seq<Iterator,Context,RContext,Attribute>(const Parser &,Iterator &,const Iterator &,const Context &,RContext &,Attribute &,boost::mpl::false_)”的引用
        with
        [
            Parser=boost::spirit::x3::detail::alternative_helper<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::kleene<boost::spirit::x3::standard::char_type>,boost::spirit::x3::extension::as_parser<char,void>::type>,boost::spirit::x3::double_type>>,
            Iterator=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>,
            Context=boost::spirit::x3::context<boost::spirit::x3::skipper_tag,const boost::spirit::x3::ascii::space_type,boost::spirit::x3::unused_type>,
            RContext=const boost::spirit::x3::unused_type,
            Attribute=std::vector<test::last,std::allocator<test::last>>
        ]
I:\boost_1_83_0\build\debug\include\boost/spirit/home/x3/core/detail/parse_into_container.hpp(215): note: 查看对正在编译的函数 模板 实例化“bool boost::spirit::x3::detail::parse_into_container_base_impl<Parser>::call<Iterator,Context,RContext,Attribute>(const Parser &,Iterator &,const Iterator &,const Context &,RContext &,Attribute &,boost::mpl::true_)”的引用
        with
        [
            Parser=boost::spirit::x3::detail::alternative_helper<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::kleene<boost::spirit::x3::standard::char_type>,boost::spirit::x3::extension::as_parser<char,void>::type>,boost::spirit::x3::double_type>>,
            Iterator=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>,
            Context=boost::spirit::x3::context<boost::spirit::x3::skipper_tag,const boost::spirit::x3::ascii::space_type,boost::spirit::x3::unused_type>,
            RContext=const boost::spirit::x3::unused_type,
            Attribute=std::vector<test::last,std::allocator<test::last>>
        ]
I:\boost_1_83_0\build\debug\include\boost/spirit/home/x3/core/detail/parse_into_container.hpp(214): note: 查看对正在编译的函数 模板 实例化“bool boost::spirit::x3::detail::parse_into_container_base_impl<Parser>::call<Iterator,Context,RContext,Attribute>(const Parser &,Iterator &,const Iterator &,const Context &,RContext &,Attribute &,boost::mpl::true_)”的引用
        with
        [
            Parser=boost::spirit::x3::detail::alternative_helper<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::kleene<boost::spirit::x3::standard::char_type>,boost::spirit::x3::extension::as_parser<char,void>::type>,boost::spirit::x3::double_type>>,
            Iterator=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>,
            Context=boost::spirit::x3::context<boost::spirit::x3::skipper_tag,const boost::spirit::x3::ascii::space_type,boost::spirit::x3::unused_type>,
            RContext=const boost::spirit::x3::unused_type,
            Attribute=std::vector<test::last,std::allocator<test::last>>
        ]
I:\boost_1_83_0\build\debug\include\boost/spirit/home/x3/core/detail/parse_into_container.hpp(304): note: 查看对正在编译的函数 模板 实例化“bool boost::spirit::x3::detail::parse_into_container_base_impl<Parser>::call<Iterator,Context,RContext,Attribute>(const Parser &,Iterator &,const Iterator &,const Context &,RContext &,Attribute &)”的引用
        with
        [
            Parser=boost::spirit::x3::detail::alternative_helper<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::kleene<boost::spirit::x3::standard::char_type>,boost::spirit::x3::extension::as_parser<char,void>::type>,boost::spirit::x3::double_type>>,
            Iterator=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>,
            Context=boost::spirit::x3::context<boost::spirit::x3::skipper_tag,const boost::spirit::x3::ascii::space_type,boost::spirit::x3::unused_type>,
            RContext=const boost::spirit::x3::unused_type,
            Attribute=std::vector<test::last,std::allocator<test::last>>
        ]
I:\boost_1_83_0\build\debug\include\boost/spirit/home/x3/core/detail/parse_into_container.hpp(303): note: 查看对正在编译的函数 模板 实例化“bool boost::spirit::x3::detail::parse_into_container_base_impl<Parser>::call<Iterator,Context,RContext,Attribute>(const Parser &,Iterator &,const Iterator &,const Context &,RContext &,Attribute &)”的引用
        with
        [
            Parser=boost::spirit::x3::detail::alternative_helper<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::kleene<boost::spirit::x3::standard::char_type>,boost::spirit::x3::extension::as_parser<char,void>::type>,boost::spirit::x3::double_type>>,
            Iterator=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>,
            Context=boost::spirit::x3::context<boost::spirit::x3::skipper_tag,const boost::spirit::x3::ascii::space_type,boost::spirit::x3::unused_type>,
            RContext=const boost::spirit::x3::unused_type,
            Attribute=std::vector<test::last,std::allocator<test::last>>
        ]
I:\boost_1_83_0\build\debug\include\boost/spirit/home/x3/operator/detail/alternative.hpp(234): note: 查看对正在编译的函数 模板 实例化“bool boost::spirit::x3::detail::parse_into_container<boost::spirit::x3::detail::alternative_helper<Left>,Iterator,Context,RContext,Attribute>(const Parser &,Iterator &,const Iterator &,const Context &,RContext &,Attribute &)”的引用
        with
        [
            Left=boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::kleene<boost::spirit::x3::standard::char_type>,boost::spirit::x3::extension::as_parser<char,void>::type>,boost::spirit::x3::double_type>,
            Iterator=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>,
            Context=boost::spirit::x3::context<boost::spirit::x3::skipper_tag,const boost::spirit::x3::ascii::space_type,boost::spirit::x3::unused_type>,
            RContext=const boost::spirit::x3::unused_type,
            Attribute=std::vector<test::last,std::allocator<test::last>>,
            Parser=boost::spirit::x3::detail::alternative_helper<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::kleene<boost::spirit::x3::standard::char_type>,boost::spirit::x3::extension::as_parser<char,void>::type>,boost::spirit::x3::double_type>>
        ]
I:\boost_1_83_0\build\debug\include\boost/spirit/home/x3/operator/detail/alternative.hpp(245): note: 查看对正在编译的函数 模板 实例化“bool boost::spirit::x3::detail::parse_into_container_impl<Parser,Context,RContext,void>::call<Iterator,Attribute>(const boost::spirit::x3::alternative<Derived,boost::spirit::x3::int_parser<int,10,1,-1>> &,Iterator &,const Iterator &,const Context &,RContext &,Attribute &,boost::mpl::true_)”的引用
        with
        [
            Parser=boost::spirit::x3::alternative<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::kleene<boost::spirit::x3::standard::char_type>,boost::spirit::x3::extension::as_parser<char,void>::type>,boost::spirit::x3::double_type>,boost::spirit::x3::int_type>,
            Context=boost::spirit::x3::context<boost::spirit::x3::skipper_tag,const boost::spirit::x3::ascii::space_type,boost::spirit::x3::unused_type>,
            RContext=const boost::spirit::x3::unused_type,
            Iterator=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>,
            Attribute=std::vector<test::last,std::allocator<test::last>>,
            Derived=boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::kleene<boost::spirit::x3::standard::char_type>,boost::spirit::x3::extension::as_parser<char,void>::type>,boost::spirit::x3::double_type>
        ]
I:\boost_1_83_0\build\debug\include\boost/spirit/home/x3/operator/detail/alternative.hpp(244): note: 查看对正在编译的函数 模板 实例化“bool boost::spirit::x3::detail::parse_into_container_impl<Parser,Context,RContext,void>::call<Iterator,Attribute>(const boost::spirit::x3::alternative<Derived,boost::spirit::x3::int_parser<int,10,1,-1>> &,Iterator &,const Iterator &,const Context &,RContext &,Attribute &,boost::mpl::true_)”的引用
        with
        [
            Parser=boost::spirit::x3::alternative<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::kleene<boost::spirit::x3::standard::char_type>,boost::spirit::x3::extension::as_parser<char,void>::type>,boost::spirit::x3::double_type>,boost::spirit::x3::int_type>,
            Context=boost::spirit::x3::context<boost::spirit::x3::skipper_tag,const boost::spirit::x3::ascii::space_type,boost::spirit::x3::unused_type>,
            RContext=const boost::spirit::x3::unused_type,
            Iterator=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>,
            Attribute=std::vector<test::last,std::allocator<test::last>>,
            Derived=boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::kleene<boost::spirit::x3::standard::char_type>,boost::spirit::x3::extension::as_parser<char,void>::type>,boost::spirit::x3::double_type>
        ]
I:\boost_1_83_0\build\debug\include\boost/spirit/home/x3/core/detail/parse_into_container.hpp(304): note: 查看对正在编译的函数 模板 实例化“bool boost::spirit::x3::detail::parse_into_container_impl<Parser,Context,RContext,void>::call<Iterator,Attribute>(const boost::spirit::x3::alternative<Derived,boost::spirit::x3::int_parser<int,10,1,-1>> &,Iterator &,const Iterator &,const Context &,RContext &,Attribute &)”的引
用
        with
        [
            Parser=boost::spirit::x3::alternative<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::kleene<boost::spirit::x3::standard::char_type>,boost::spirit::x3::extension::as_parser<char,void>::type>,boost::spirit::x3::double_type>,boost::spirit::x3::int_type>,
            Context=boost::spirit::x3::context<boost::spirit::x3::skipper_tag,const boost::spirit::x3::ascii::space_type,boost::spirit::x3::unused_type>,
            RContext=const boost::spirit::x3::unused_type,
            Iterator=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>,
            Attribute=std::vector<test::last,std::allocator<test::last>>,
            Derived=boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::kleene<boost::spirit::x3::standard::char_type>,boost::spirit::x3::extension::as_parser<char,void>::type>,boost::spirit::x3::double_type>
        ]
I:\boost_1_83_0\build\debug\include\boost/spirit/home/x3/core/detail/parse_into_container.hpp(303): note: 查看对正在编译的函数 模板 实例化“bool boost::spirit::x3::detail::parse_into_container_impl<Parser,Context,RContext,void>::call<Iterator,Attribute>(const boost::spirit::x3::alternative<Derived,boost::spirit::x3::int_parser<int,10,1,-1>> &,Iterator &,const Iterator &,const Context &,RContext &,Attribute &)”的引
用
        with
        [
            Parser=boost::spirit::x3::alternative<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::kleene<boost::spirit::x3::standard::char_type>,boost::spirit::x3::extension::as_parser<char,void>::type>,boost::spirit::x3::double_type>,boost::spirit::x3::int_type>,
            Context=boost::spirit::x3::context<boost::spirit::x3::skipper_tag,const boost::spirit::x3::ascii::space_type,boost::spirit::x3::unused_type>,
            RContext=const boost::spirit::x3::unused_type,
            Iterator=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>,
            Attribute=std::vector<test::last,std::allocator<test::last>>,
            Derived=boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::kleene<boost::spirit::x3::standard::char_type>,boost::spirit::x3::extension::as_parser<char,void>::type>,boost::spirit::x3::double_type>
        ]
I:\boost_1_83_0\build\debug\include\boost/spirit/home/x3/operator/list.hpp(34): note: 查看对正在编译的函数 模板 实例化“bool boost::spirit::x3::detail::parse_into_container<Left,Iterator,Context,RContext,Attribute>(const Parser &,Iterator &,const Iterator &,const Context &,RContext &,Attribute &)”的引用
        with
        [
            Left=boost::spirit::x3::alternative<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::kleene<boost::spirit::x3::standard::char_type>,boost::spirit::x3::extension::as_parser<char,void>::type>,boost::spirit::x3::double_type>,boost::spirit::x3::int_type>,
            Iterator=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>,
            Context=boost::spirit::x3::context<boost::spirit::x3::skipper_tag,const boost::spirit::x3::ascii::space_type,boost::spirit::x3::unused_type>,
            RContext=const boost::spirit::x3::unused_type,
            Attribute=std::vector<test::last,std::allocator<test::last>>,
            Parser=boost::spirit::x3::alternative<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::kleene<boost::spirit::x3::standard::char_type>,boost::spirit::x3::extension::as_parser<char,void>::type>,boost::spirit::x3::double_type>,boost::spirit::x3::int_type>
        ]
I:\boost_1_83_0\build\debug\include\boost/spirit/home/x3/core/parse.hpp(119): note: 查看对正在编译的函数 模板 实例化“bool boost::spirit::x3::list<Derived,boost::spirit::x3::extension::as_parser<char,void>::type>::parse<Iterator,boost::spirit::x3::context<boost::spirit::x3::skipper_tag,const boost::spirit::x3::char_class<boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii,boost::spirit::x3::space_tag>,boost::spirit::x3::unused_type>,const boost::spirit::x3::unused_type,Attribute>(Iterator &,const Iterator &,const Context &,RContext &,Attribute &) const”的引用
        with
        [
            Derived=boost::spirit::x3::alternative<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::sequence<boost::spirit::x3::kleene<boost::spirit::x3::standard::char_type>,boost::spirit::x3::extension::as_parser<char,void>::type>,boost::spirit::x3::double_type>,boost::spirit::x3::int_type>,
            Iterator=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>,
            Attribute=std::vector<test::last,std::allocator<test::last>>,
            Context=boost::spirit::x3::context<boost::spirit::x3::skipper_tag,const boost::spirit::x3::ascii::space_type,boost::spirit::x3::unused_type>,
            RContext=const boost::spirit::x3::unused_type
        ]
I:\boost_1_83_0\build\debug\include\boost/spirit/home/x3/core/parse.hpp(119): note: 查看对正在编译的函数 模板 实例化“bool
```

**

Who can point out where the mistake is, or tell me the detailed reason.

I would greatly appreciate it

**

**update**
**Even if I modify the following code according to your reply
Compilation still reports errors, never before has there been such confusion**

```
namespace  test {

struct last;
struct pre{
    std::vector<char> cs;
    double first;
    std::vector<x3::forward_ast<last>> second;
};
struct last : x3::variant<boost::recursive_wrapper<pre>,intmax_t>{
    using base_type::base_type;
    using base_type::operator=;
};

}
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(test::pre,cs,first);


std::string input = R"(
        123,xxxxxx|456.00,45645,ffffffff|33.22
    )";


    std::vector<test::last> out;
    bool r = x3::phrase_parse(input.begin(), input.end(),  (( (!x3::int_ >> *~x3::char_("|")) >> '|' >> x3::double_) | x3::int_) % ',' >> x3::eoi, x3::ascii::space, out);
    if(r && (g_iter == g_end)){
        std::cout << "parse success!" << std::endl;
    }else{
        std::cerr << "parse fail!" << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell use what you want to achieve, and show the actual self-contained that re-creates the problem?

Comment: As an exercise。I want to implement parsing C language and serialize it into a custom structure.。The syntax of C in Backus-Naur Form：https://cs.wmich.edu/~gupta/teaching/cs4850/sumII06/The%20syntax%20of%20C%20in%20Backus-Naur%20form.htm

Comment: I mean by editing the question and adding a MVCE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example or SSCCE http://sscce.org/

Comment: I submitted a simple instance code

Could you please help me take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear to me what you wanted to parse.

- the `int_` will also match in e.g. "123ab|234.45"
- the `*char_` matches everything. That includes `'|'` so `pre` will never match
- the third member (`second`) has no parser expression, so it can't be matched

I commented out `second` and fixed up the rules to avoid the problems listed above. As always, being specific helps:

```
auto pre = x3::rule<struct pre, AST::pre>{"pre"} = //
    (*~x3::char_("|") >> '|' >> x3::double_);
auto last = x3::rule<struct last, AST::last>{"last"} = //
    !x3::int_ >> pre | x3::int_;
```

Now you can parse with

```
bool r = phrase_parse(          //
    input.begin(), input.end(), //
    last % ',' >> x3::eoi,      //
    x3::space, out);
```

### Live Demo

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10e4cb57ba64e973)**

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/support/ast/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace x3  = boost::spirit::x3;
namespace AST {
    struct last;
    struct pre {
        std::vector<char>                  cs;
        double                             first;
        std::vector<x3::forward_ast<last>> second;
    };
    struct last : x3::variant<boost::recursive_wrapper<pre>, intmax_t> {
        using base_type::base_type;
        using base_type::operator=;
    };
} // namespace AST

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::pre, cs, first/*, second*/)

int main() {
    for (std::string const input :
         {
             R"(123,xxxxxx|456.00,45645,ffffffff|33.22)",
         }) //
    {

        std::vector<AST::last> out;

        auto pre = x3::rule<struct pre, AST::pre>{"pre"} = //
            (*~x3::char_("|") >> '|' >> x3::double_);
        auto last = x3::rule<struct last, AST::last>{"last"} = //
            !x3::int_ >> pre | x3::int_;

        bool r = phrase_parse(          //
            input.begin(), input.end(), //
            last % ',' >> x3::eoi,      //
            x3::space, out);

        if (r) {
            std::cout << "parse success!" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cerr << "parse fail!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
parse success!
```

With debug output:

```xml
<last>
  <try>123,xxxxxx|456.00,45</try>
  <success>,xxxxxx|456.00,45645</success>
  <attributes>123</attributes>
</last>
<last>
  <try>xxxxxx|456.00,45645,</try>
  <pre>
    <try>xxxxxx|456.00,45645,</try>
    <success>,45645,ffffffff|33.2</success>
    <attributes>[[x, x, x, x, x, x], 456]</attributes>
  </pre>
  <success>,45645,ffffffff|33.2</success>
  <attributes>[[x, x, x, x, x, x], 456]</attributes>
</last>
<last>
  <try>45645,ffffffff|33.22</try>
  <success>,ffffffff|33.22</success>
  <attributes>45645</attributes>
</last>
<last>
  <try>ffffffff|33.22</try>
  <pre>
    <try>ffffffff|33.22</try>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[[f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f], 33.22]</attributes>
  </pre>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[[f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f], 33.22]</attributes>
</last>
```

Comment: There are indeed errors in the code, but the focus is  why it cannot be compiled through。

Also, I noticed that you  code【 BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::pre, cs, first/*, second*/) 】 why did you annotate second

Comment: Please help me again, I have never been so confused before

Comment: [Off Topic: Can you stop begging for help? I'm here anyways. If I am somehow not able to help, it should be fine either way.]

Comment: Re "Why did you annotate second" - I lterally said in the answer text: _"the third member (second) has no parser expression, so it can't be matched //
I commented out second and fixed up the rules to avoid the problems listed above"_. That's it.

Comment: By the way, to the edit (don't edit your question, just post a new question if required), you *can* do it but don't mix `recursive_wrapper` and `x3::variant` https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbfed070da559e7e - note that since there are no rules, (1) debug info is gone (2) you will run into ambiguous attribute propagation much sooner.  I haven't checked the attributes propagated correctly.

Comment: So, it does propagate correctly: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3300e91fc0a8e951

Comment: Because I had time to spare and I know it's going to be your next question anyways: Here's the grammar including the recursive AST and samples. I had to make up a syntax for you to adopt, because, like I said "the third member (second) has no parser expression" - I made one up just so I can demo: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e160ced64a15a48

Comment: Note it's probably more efficient to `forward_ast` the entire vector instead: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/21b16ed0e9fd2920 - or just employ the fact that c++17 provides support for incomplete type arguments to some containers: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ef6da4ff685c7b0

Comment: I'm starting to understand the meaning of your sentence【"the third member (second) has no parser expression, so it can't be matched 】

In actual examples, there is indeed no expression to match it, so it should be deleted

Question 1:

In your reply, you suggest avoiding mixing x3:: variant, boost:: recursive_ Wrapper, but in actual language parsing, there is definitely a phenomenon of nested recursion. At this time, x3:: variant and boost:: recursive_ There will definitely be mixed use of wrappers. What should I do at this time

Comment: I have reviewed your example in detail【 https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ef6da4ff685c7b0 】It answered my question above

Comment: Are there any more example codes in this area that I will study one by one

Comment: I have many dozens of examples in this site. There's of course the library examples